# Why cy.wait does not work on the first load?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have written this test,

```
it.only('Should have Min Bed filter with desired options and filter data with it', ()=>{
    const options = [
        {value: 1, title: '1+'},
        {value: 2, title: '2+'},
        {value: 3, title: '3+'},
    ];
    options.forEach(option=>{
        cy.get('.filter-title').contains('Beds').click();
        cy.server().route('POST','/api/residential/search?size=20&page=0&sort=price,ASC').as('waiting'+option['value']);
        cy.get('.ant-radio-wrapper > span').contains(option['title']).click();
        cy.wait('@waiting'+option['value']).then((xhr)=>{
            assert.equal(xhr.request.body.bedrooms.min, option['value']);
        });
    });
});
```

this test does not work on the first load of the website. But, if I re-run this quickly, it will work fine.

Comment: Did you check on first load have you get console under. it.only('Should have Min Bed filter with desired options and filter data with it', ()=>{}

Comment: @jatin.7744 Yes, I have added console.log under it.only and it works fine. Please note that click on buttons works fine, the only thing that does not work on the first load is cy.wait.

Comment: can please give me more code and information regarding this so that I debug and find some solution for you. What I doubt as you say we are not getting the data on the very first load else we are getting on click action. So I wants to debug over forEach loop is the option which we are iterating are getting ? See as per my knowledge and on the basis for our discuss I found their is small issue in you code where on first load some data are missing to loop can you give me error message for the same what message we are getting.